# Pandas dataframe copy is not same as original

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.3

I just ran in to what appears to be a very odd bug in Pandas:

```
from pandas import *
cleanData = DataFrame({'Q18': {751.0: 'None',
  754.0: '3',
  757.0: '10',
  758.0: nan,
  759.0: nan,
  763.0: '40',
  766.0: nan,
  767.0: 'None',
  769.0: '1',
  770.0: nan}})

manualCorrections = \
{
 'Q18':
 {
  751: 0,
  767: 0,
  1097: 10
 }
}

manualCleanedData = cleanData.copy()

print(manualCleanedData['Q18'].loc[751])

for col_name, corrections in manualCorrections.items():
    for lab, val in corrections.items():
        manualCleanedData[col_name].loc[lab] = val

finalCleanData = manualCleanedData.copy()

print(manualCleanedData['Q18'].loc[751])
print(finalCleanData['Q18'].loc[751])
```

Output:

```
None
0
None
```

where the Nones are string 'None', not python None

Also,

```
manualCleanedData == manualCleanedData.copy()
```

throws an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5d010e43aca8> in <module>()
----> 1 manualCleanedData == manualCleanedData.copy()

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/ops.py in f(self, other)
    873     def f(self, other):
    874         if isinstance(other, pd.DataFrame):    # Another DataFrame
--> 875             return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)
    876         elif isinstance(other, pd.Series):
    877             return self._combine_series_infer(other, func)

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in _compare_frame(self, other, func, str_rep)
   2860             raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
   2861                              'DataFrame objects')
-> 2862         return self._compare_frame_evaluate(other, func, str_rep)
   2863 
   2864     def _flex_compare_frame(self, other, func, str_rep, level):

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in _compare_frame_evaluate(self, other, func, str_rep)
   2842             def _compare(a, b):
   2843                 return dict([(col, func(a[col], b[col])) for col in a.columns])
-> 2844             new_data = expressions.evaluate(_compare, str_rep, self, other)
   2845             return self._constructor(data=new_data, index=self.index,
   2846                                      columns=self.columns, copy=False)

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    174     if use_numexpr:
    175         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 176                          **eval_kwargs)
    177     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
    178 

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, truediv, **eval_kwargs)
    114 
    115     if result is None:
--> 116         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error)
    117 
    118     return result

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, **eval_kwargs)
     62     if _TEST_MODE:
     63         _store_test_result(False)
---> 64     return op(a, b)
     65 
     66 

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in _compare(a, b)
   2841         if self.columns.is_unique:
   2842             def _compare(a, b):
-> 2843                 return dict([(col, func(a[col], b[col])) for col in a.columns])
   2844             new_data = expressions.evaluate(_compare, str_rep, self, other)
   2845             return self._constructor(data=new_data, index=self.index,

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2841         if self.columns.is_unique:
   2842             def _compare(a, b):
-> 2843                 return dict([(col, func(a[col], b[col])) for col in a.columns])
   2844             new_data = expressions.evaluate(_compare, str_rep, self, other)
   2845             return self._constructor(data=new_data, index=self.index,

/home/space/phujfj/Installations/Python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other)
    540             name = _maybe_match_name(self, other)
    541             if len(self) != len(other):
--> 542                 raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
    543             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, other.values),
    544                                      index=self.index, name=name)

ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

Removing the 1097: 10 entry from manualCorrections prevents the bug from appearing.

Am I just being dumb or is there something very broken here?

Pandas version: 0.13.1

Python version: 3.3.3

OS: Linux x86_64

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy. This is bascially an unsafe operation, modifying using chained indexing (e.g. the ``df[col].loc[row] = value``; you *can* instead do: ``df.loc[row,col] = value`` to avoid this issue (even better is to use ``update/replace`` in any event.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to using replace and it works fine.

I didn't get a warning printed about those assignments, and I don't get an exception when I set the relevant option either. Is there something dodgy going on there? To be honest I still think there's a bug hiding somewhere: a copy shouldn't be different to the source.

Comment: no...the issue is that the chained assignment, sometimes can generate a view; it makes it non-deterministic as a result.